# How to stop looping through array when index is empty?

Tags: c++, arrays, break

If I have an array of size `MAX_SIZE` and only have 20 index occupied how do you make it so that it stops printing 0s after `itemList[20]`? (I am reading in from a text file)

```
const int MAX_SIZE = 1000;
item itemList[MAX_SIZE];

for(int i= 0; i<MAX_SIZE;i++)
{
itemList[i].Print(); //prints members in item

  if(i==19) // I used this just to see what I was printing properly
   {         //I know it is bad practice so I would like an alternative.
       break; //Also, it is only possible if you have access to the text file.
   }
}
```

Comment: This code will not compile since the if (i == 19) is outside the loop. However, if I am understanding your question correctly, you can change the for condition from i < MAX_SIZE to i < 20 to stop after 20.

Comment: @Caitlin Wilks fixed, I was specifically instructed to not hard code into it, that is why I ask(It is a school assignment).

Comment: If you're asking how to extend it to work for any number, you would have to store the number of elements and increment it as you add more. Alternatively, you could use std::vector to have a dynamic array that keeps track of itself.

Comment: @Caitlin Wilks I have not seen vectors in class, I will probably next semester.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can perform a basic check:

```
if(itemList[i].Function() == 0) break;
```

Comment: **basic** should probably be bolded.

Comment: @user3598064 if this problem is resolved, you should accept the appropriate answer.

Comment: @awesomeyi my bad, I am new here, just did as you said.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to `break`, you can use a `while` loop:

```
int i = 0;
while (itemList[i] != 0 && i < MAX_SIZE)
{
    itemList[i].Print();
    i++;
}
```

Replace `itemList[i] != 0` with whatever expression you're using to determine whether the element is occupied or not.

Alternatively, keep track of how many elements there are as you build up the array from the file, and only loop that many times.

Better still, remember that you're using C++, not C. Add elements from the file to a container such as `std::vector` instead of a raw array, then just loop through the whole thing. This also fixes a serious bug in your code; namely, that you will have undefined behaviour when there are more than 1000 entries in the file.

Comment: I don't know too much about C++, but it seems your `while` loop is actually an obfuscated `for` loop with a larger than usual condition – I'd think that using a `for` loop with a `break` inside the loop body would be the clearest way to convey the intent. Could you explain why we'd want to avoid `break`? Anyway, +1 for the vector recommendation.

Comment: @amon I didn't necessarily say break should be avoided, I'm merely supplying an alternative solution since one using `break` has been supplied by another person.

Answer (score 0):

```
const int MAX_SIZE = 1000;
item itemList[MAX_SIZE];

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(aitemList / sizeof(*itemList)); i++)
{
    if (itemList[i] != 0)
        itemList[i].Print();
}
```

or use a vector

```
std::vector<int> itemList;

for (int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++) 
{
    if (itemList[i] != 0)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A short lesson in:

- correctly iterating through a null-terminated pointer array
- cleaning up arrays of pointers in an exception safe way
- solving your problem correctly

.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

struct Oper {
    void exec() const { cout << "Hello\n"; }
    ~Oper() { cout << "deleted\n"; }
};


int main()
{
    Oper* myArray[1000];
    fill(begin(myArray), end(myArray), nullptr);

    // make a sentinel to ensure that the array is cleaned up if there is an exception
    std::shared_ptr<void> sentinel(&myArray, [&](void*) {
        // clean up array
        for (auto p = begin(myArray) ; p != end(myArray) ; ++p) {
            delete *p;
        }
    });

    myArray[0] = new Oper;
    myArray[1] = new Oper;
    myArray[2] = new Oper;
    myArray[4] = new Oper; // note: missed 3

    for(auto p = begin(myArray) ; p != end(myArray) && *p ; ++p) {
        (*p)->exec();
    }

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Compiling the source code....
$g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o demo -lm -pthread -lgmpxx -lgmp -lreadline 2>&1

Executing the program....
$demo 
Hello
Hello
Hello
deleted
deleted
deleted
deleted
```

Comment: This is dreadful. OP's code is already simple and safe; your code does a bunch of complicated stuff for no reason at all.  `fill(...` can be replaced by `= { };`.

Comment: It's difficult to tell whether the OPs code is simple and safe since it's incomplete.
fill(... and - {}; are logically equivalent, but you're right - initialising at the point of declaration is better.
Of course we should ask why the OP is using a fixed size array at all. Perhaps that's a requirement, perhaps not. 
As for storing pointers, of course I could have used an array of unique_ptr, or even an array of Oper. But again, I don't know from the OP's requirements whether Oper is a large complex object or a simple one. I have chosen to be pessimistic and avoid un-necessary constructor calls.

Comment: @RichardHodges Yes, it was required by my professor, he said to set it at 1000, and to not hardcode it, hence the `const int MAX_SIZE = 1000;
item itemList[MAX_SIZE];`

Answer (score -4):

```
for(int i= 0; i<MAX_SIZE && i<20;i++)
```

it looks better because using of break is a bad pattern.

Comment: The question is about how to end the loop once a 0 is found, not how to hard code it to end the loop after the 20th element.